# textview appears faded android

Tags: android, textview, custom-adapter

I am using a custom adapter to populate a listview.The list item is made of 2 textviews and the result is the following:
[image]

Any reason why the textview appears faded?

Comment: Give us some code - the adapter and the XML for the rows.

Comment: set the text color of TextView to black to make it visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might not have set the textcolor and tht could be a reason. set the textcolor to the textviews to black and it would be done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have made your textViews in listView row as enabled:"false" .
If so give your textView textColor = "#000000" and otherwise also give textColor